# How to print $ as part of string in shell script?

Tags: scripts, docker

I'm trying to use some string that contains $ something like this 'Te$t' as an environment variable In a docker-compose file but when the value is printed its appears like 'Te'

no idea how to print the entire string, I have tried `"Te\$t"` but didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved by adding $$ instead of one if there is better solution please post it as well.